# DataTables - configurable query

Tags: c#, t-sql, configuration, datatable

I have collected data from two different sources, for instance: from a online resource and from a local database. The results from these sources is each stored in their own `System.Data.DataTable` object(flat structure).

I want to be able to query these sources with a join-query that i can configure in App.Config. How can this be accomplished?

`DataTable` `dtPublicCompanyBlacklist` contains the following columns:

```
id 
name
```

`DataTable` `dtMyCompanyCustomerSource` contains the following columns:

```
id 
salesTotal
e-mail
```

I want to be able to write something like following (as `string`):

```
select a.name, b.salesTotal, b.e-mail 
from dtPublicCompanyBlacklist a, dtMyCompanyCustomerSource  b 
where a.id = b.id
```

The users of the application should be able to modify the query without having to recompile the sourcecode. I have not found that Linq can be used like this.

Comment: _"query these sources with a join-query that i can configure in App.Config"_ can you explain it better? It's not clear at all.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Updated with example, hope it clarifies the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please find below example. You can do it with linq query.

```
var result = from dataRows1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
             join dataRows2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
             on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("ID")
             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
             {
                dataRows1.Field<string>("ID"),
                dataRows1.Field<string>("name"),
                dataRows2.Field<int>("stock")
              }, false);
```

Comment: Is there any way this can be done by having the query, that you show here, as a string that is read at runtime from lets say the App.Config file. I want users to be able to modify query without having to recompile.

Comment: Then you might need to write above query in app.config and compile and execute it via c# code.                                                 [Compiling C# Code At run time](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime)